# Newline (\n) handled differently by zsh vs bash - how to fix?

Tags: bash, zsh, newlines

If I run the script below using `zsh` and `bash`, I'm getting different results.
Interestingly, this is caused by the `\n` newlines in the input string.

Using `zsh`, I get the **correct** result:

```
rene@MININT-G1P7G69 Desktop % zsh bash_vs_zsh.sh 
Hashed signature: AgTW6P8HlAlfOikDPMa/Q92tX2a0GSdDLVeeZE219BQ=
```

With `bash`, I'm getting an **incorrect** hash:

```
rene@MININT-G1P7G69 Desktop % bash bash_vs_zsh.sh
Hashed signature: R2FaEYqGsb9QtCQTJEvySoqs0VEgtCyWEWg1R5jRzEo=
```

If I remove the `\n` instances from the input, the results are equal.

```
signature="get\ndbs\n\nmon, 27 apr 2020 16:11:57 gmt\n\n"

masterKey="t7ejJOwk0HEgkeYCm9v3n8vNwVaW27uriUmTTc3JcBtwqHBfwqO1tAJqKOBpeivurzPl1DxsNFUehEQN5lzGRw=="

hashedSignature=$(echo -n $signature | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:$(echo -n $masterKey | base64 --decode | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x"') -binary | base64)
echo "Hashed signature: $hashedSignature"
```

How can I make `bash` behave as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Bash and in Zsh `"\n"` becomes just `\n` after quote removal, not a newline character. The difference is in how `echo` builtin prints it later. In Zsh `echo` with or without `-e` interprets `\n` (and other sequences) like `echo -e` in Bash; but in Bash `echo` without `-e` doesn't. You have at least two possibilities:

   - Define `signature` as you did and let `echo -en` interpret `\n` substrings later.
   - Define `signature` so it actually contains newlines in the first place. To get newlines at this stage you can use [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html):

     ```
     signature=$'get\ndbs\n\nmon, 27 apr 2020 16:11:57 gmt\n\n'
     ```

     But then you need to make `echo` *not* interpret sequences just in case the string you want to pass should contain one or more sequences literally. The idea is to have all the interpretation in one place.

   In general [`printf` is better than `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618). I would choose ANSI-C quoting while defining the variable, then `printf` that prints literally.
2. In Bash you need to [explicitly double-quote variables and command substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618), unless you know what you're doing. Zsh treats double-quoted or unquoted variables like Bash treats double-quoted ones, so to replicate the behavior of Zsh you do want to quote in Bash for sure.

The following snippet outputs the same string (the one you called "correct") in Bash and in Zsh:

```
signature=$'get\ndbs\n\nmon, 27 apr 2020 16:11:57 gmt\n\n'
masterKey="t7ejJOwk0HEgkeYCm9v3n8vNwVaW27uriUmTTc3JcBtwqHBfwqO1tAJqKOBpeivurzPl1DxsNFUehEQN5lzGRw=="

hashedSignature="$(printf '%s' "$signature" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:"$(printf '%s' "$masterKey" | base64 --decode | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x"')" -binary | base64)"
echo "Hashed signature: $hashedSignature"
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about double quotes. Changed that. Instead of using ANSI-C quoting, I figured that using "echo -en" instead of "echo -n" does also work: `hashedSignature="$(echo -en "$signature...` - thoughts?

Comment: @Krumelur What do you mean by "thoughts"? If you have a *well defined* question about `echo -en`, please ask a new question. If my answer does not solve your problem, please give specific feedback. I don't really want to start an open-ended discussion here. Super User is a Q&A site and "thoughts?" is not a good question. I'm still willing to help you with whatever the new(?) problem is, but let's keep it in the gist of the site.

Comment: Um, no need to be offended. All I wanted to know was if using "-en" is a valid alternative or if it is just working by coincidence. Because if it is a valid option you might want to add it to make your answer even better.

Comment: @Krumelur You're on to something. The first point of my answer is somewhat misleading. I will improve it.

Comment: @Krumelur Done.